# Notepad ++ How to remove day and month from date?

Tags: regex, notepad++

i have text like this :

```
EU 1097-2002-25-06-2002.pdf
EU 1255-2007-26-10-2007.pdf
EU 1513-2002-EC-27-06-2002.pdf
EU 2001-18-EC-22-09-2003.pdf
EU 2001-47-EC-15-01-2003.pdf
```

in last part of any row the full date is apear
i need to remove day and month without year from this lines

```
EU 1097-2002-2002.pdf
EU 1255-2007-2007.pdf
EU 1513-2002-EC-2002.pdf
EU 2001-18-EC-2003.pdf
EU 2001-47-EC-2003.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Find what : `-\d{2}-\d{2}(?=-\d{4}[.]\w+)`
- Replace with :
- Search mode : Regular Expression

It tries to find : dash & 2 digits & dash & 2 digits.
But only if those are followed by : dash & 4 digits & extension.

Since only the day and month part get matched, replacing with nothing will remove them.

Answer (score 0):

6 characters followed by 4 characters and a dot:

```
.{6}(?=.{4}\.)
```

replace with an empty string.

The lookahead assertion `(?=  )` means *followed by* but it doesn't consume characters, it's only a test.